# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли так оформить пояснение?

Общедоступное наркотическое средство — водка — приносило
замедленные и мгновенные трагедии.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше поставить запятые, если никаких добавочных значений нет. Ваш пример соответствует следующему положению : (Цитирую Розенталя  http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm   )

**Одиночное нераспространенное** приложение, стоящее после нарицательного существительного,обособляется, если определяемое существительное **имеет при себе пояснительные слова,** например: Он оставил коня, поднял голову и увидал своего корреспондента, дьякона (Тургенев); Ухаживала за мной о
дна девушка, полька (Горький).

1. Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений употребляется тире:

а)      если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а именно», например: Утвержден новый государственный флаг Российской Федерации – трехцветное полотнище с белой, синей и красной продольными полосами;

б)      перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим **в конце предложения,** если подчеркивается самостоятельность или дается разъяснение такого приложения, например: Я не слишком люблю это дерево – осину (Тургенев); Объехали какую-то старую плотину, потонувшую в крапиве, и давно высохший пруд – глубокую яругу, заросшую бурьяном выше человеческого роста (Бунин); Рядом помещалась каморка – хранилище каталогов (Гранин); Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике... (Горбатов). Ср. одиночное приложение после распространенного имени собственного: Добро пожаловать в столицу Украины – Киев!

в)      для выделения с двух сторон приложений, носящих пояснительный характер (обычно в художественной речи), например: Какая-то ненатуральная зелень – творение скучных беспрерывных дождей – покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы... (Гоголь); Легкие судороги – признак сильного чувства – пробежали по его широким губам... (Тургенев); Смотритель ночлежки – отставной солдат скобелевских времен – шел следом за хозяином (Федин).

У Вас ОДИНОЧНОЕ, НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНОЕ, **НЕ В КОНЦЕ** предложения. Зачем менять обычные запятые на тире? Какой смысл? Ошибки, конечно, не будет, можно объяснить особым авторским выделением,но зачем? Да запятые и смотрятся здесь лучше.

Comment: Что-то я уже совсем... А не подходит ли это под п. 3 того же Розенталя? Второе тире опускается... если в подобной конструкции приложение предшествует определяемому слову, например: Самый лживый, лицемерный и самый влиятельный из всех «учителей жизни» – церковь, проповедуя «любовь к ближнему как к самому себе», в прошлом жгла десятки тысяч людей на кострах, благословляла «религиозные» войны (Горький); Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны – спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Из газет);

Comment: Кстати в книжке даны другие примеры: На совещании выступили академики - участники симпозиума... и если приложение предшествует определяемому слову: Действующее лицо очерка - молодой человек сказал...

Comment: Людмила, пример из Розенталя. 

>Он — инвалид — продолжал работать и помогать другим. Обратите внимание, тире выделяет нераспространенное приложение.

Comment: Здесь добавочное обстоят. знач уступки "несмотря на то , что инвалид.2

Comment: Людмила, не только значение уступки, но и пояснения.

Comment: Alenka, я  сочла приложением слово "водка", потому что Вы ЕГО выделили, т.е. обособили, да ещё и "приносилО". А здесь, Вы правы, приложение "Общедоступное наркотическое средство", но тогда оно стоит ПЕРЕД определяемым словом и по общим правилам не обособляется, но так как здесь действительно причинное значение, то обособляется. И опять-таки, если просто пояснение, то запятая: Общедоступное наркотическое средство,водка приносилА замедленные и мгновенные трагедии. А уж если усилить, то можно и тире, только ПОСЛЕ приложения, а не после ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕГО

Comment: Серж, конечно,и  пояснение тоже, но это -причина обособления, а слово "водка" ничего такого не несёт, да мы уже и выяснили, что Алёнка написала предложение в таком виде, что вышло, что "водка" - приложение, а на самом деле "водка"-здесь подлежащее, его выделять тире ни к чему.

Comment: Это меняет суть дела. Здесь вы абсолютно правы!

Comment: Нет. Я не это имела ввиду. Что-то я всех совсем запутала. Водка именно приложение у этого автора, потому что он написал "приносилО", средство приносило, я тоже думала просто заменить на приносила, но ведь этого делать, наверное, нельзя... Я, видимо, все же склоняюсь к варианту Vera. Так, мне кажется, выглядит лучше. :) Хоть это  и не критерий.

Comment: Дело хозяйское, но так разве выглядит лучше:"Общедоступное наркотическое средство — водка приносилО замедленные и мгновенные трагедии"? Получается "водка приносило", а если через дефис, то вообще странно, это ж не 2 одиночных нарицат. сущ.

Comment: Ужас! Что же делать-то? Почему-то мне кажется, что запятая здесь не смотрится, но и тире смущают именно краткостью пояснения.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что здесь приложение имеет значение причины: Общедоступное наркотическое средство — водка приносила замедленные и мгновенные трагедии.

Приложение обособляется с помощью тире, если оно относится к НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНОМУ  СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОМУ  и имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение.

Исправленному  верить (приносила).

Comment: Alenka, если так хочется поставить тире-ради бога, только измените О на А - и всё будет нормально:Общедоступное наркотическое средство — водка приносилА замедленные и мгновенные трагедии.- согласуйте подлежащее и сказуемое

Comment: Кто Вам сказал, что этого делать нельзя, это всего лишь исправление грамматической ошибки.Там же не написали, где подлежащее, а где приложение?

Comment: Да, наверное, это наилучшее решение.

Answer (score 0):

Такое оформление вполне корректно. Посредством тире выделяются приложения, носящие пояснительный характер ***и перед ним можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а ''именно'' или ''то есть"***. Ср.: На улице мальчик — продавец газет — что-то выкрикивал.

См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Дополнение.

> Артиллерийская или пулеметная установка, у которой подвижная часть станка — тумба — крепится к палубе корабля, называется тумбовой установкой.
>
> Другое отравляющее вещество — дифосген — представляет собой жидкость.

***Во всех приведенных примерах при помощи тире выделено одиночное приложение.***

***Трудные случаи пунктуации. Розенталь Д. Э. Былинский.***

Comment: Все зависит от текста. В вашем примере это вставка с дополнительным значением, а там, похоже, вся статья про водку.

Comment:  Смысл такой: так как водка является общедоступным средством, она приносила замедленные и мгновенные трагедии.

Comment: Это не вставка, а уточняющее приложение. Ср.: Общедоступное наркотическое средство —( а именно) водка... Не вижу здесь об-го значения. То же в моем примере:  На улице мальчик ( а именно) — продавец газет....

Comment: Нет, статья не про водку, а про рычаги. ))) Это здесь только так,  поверхностное сетование.

Comment: Статья может быть не про водку, но нужно видеть контекст, то есть в связи с чем зашел разговор о водке. Без контекста о правильности оформления судить сложно, предложение со вставкой выглядит странно.